# How to generate space in between variables in pl/sql

Tags: html, plsql

I have been wanting to generate a space between the 2 variables b_state and b_postal_code. What method should i use? The following code is use inside pl/sql.

```
<p> || b_state ||'        ' ||b_postal_code || </p>
```

Comment: Please make your question more clear, and provide more information

Comment: What is wrong with what you have so far? Since the output is for HTML there is no point using more than one whitespace character. Is that the issue perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

1. check the database settings to manipulate special characters first.

   input below bold text commands into query editor and run it.

   > **SHOW DEFINE;**

   define "&"
2. and then, input below to permit to use special characters.

   > **SET DEFINE OFF;**
3. Just use **'&nbsp'** HTML Tag.

   > <p> || b_state || '& nbsp;& nbsp;& nbsp;' ||b_postal_code || </p>

Comment: i ran it and it prompt me to enter a substitude value for &nbsp. What should i put? I just simply put a value such as 1, the code compile but no blank space is display

Comment: This is a question about using tools then, not PL/SQL. The PL/SQL language has no special treatment for `&` characters. You'll need to tell us what tool you are using to compile your procedure.

Comment: i am using oracle sql developer to run my code. i have try show define and set define off, but it is showing me syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try: `chr(32)`

```
<p> || b_state || chr(32) ||b_postal_code || </p>
```

For `&nbsp` you need to add `set define off;` on beginning of your script. `&` is for substitute variables and to ignore its spe cial function you need execute `set define off;` before starting script.